# php scope of Global variables in a loop

Tags: php

This code connects to a first database, loops and picks up a field called 'id' and use the id as a connection[database name] to another database in a function. All seemed to work except that in the function, the value of id does not change so cannot connect to db, even though it changes in the local variable. I suspect i need to unsett and set. Any help? Thanks

```
<?

$dbhost = "***";
$dbname = "users";
$dbuser = "****";
$dbpass = "***";

function myRecordHandler($record)
{
    global $dbhost;
    global $dbuser;
    global $dbpass;
    global $id;
    global $conn2;

    $db = mysql_select_db($id,$conn2) ;
    $quantity = $record["QUANTITY"];
    $price = $record["PRICE"];
    $mytotal ="INSERT into `mytotal`(`quantity`,`price`) VALUES ($quantity,$price)";
    mysql_query($mytotal,$conn2);
}

$conn1 = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, TRUE) or die("MySQL Error: " .mysql_error());
$conn2 = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, TRUE) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());

mysql_select_db($dbname,$conn1) or die("MySQL Error: " . mysql_error());
$query = "SELECT id,url FROM table userdata";
$result = mysql_query($query,$conn1);
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{
    $id =$row['id'];
    $url=$row['url'];
    MagicParser_parse($url,"myRecordHandler","xml|PRODUCTS/PRODUCT/");
}
?>
```

Comment: Just a notice: Your code seems to be prone to SQL-Injections as you are not escaping the values.

Comment: Hard to tell, whats the problem. Add some debug output of `$id` on different places in your script for better understanding.

Comment: debugging shows there is only one value set for the id in the function.

Comment: Hmm very messy. why have 2 mysql connections to the same thing??

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that `myRecordHandler()` is being called from within `MagicParser_parse()`. It's probably being called within a separate execution context that doesn't share the same global name space. This is just a hunch based on the fact that you're passing in `"myRecordHandler"` as a string.

Comment: sure. there is an include file. anyway, printing out the values of id in the function shows only one item. This could mean there should be some sort of unsetting and setting of global variables withing the function